# Correct Place to Put a Non-Publicly Exposed Function AMD

Tags: javascript, function, scope, amd

I have a use case where a publicly exposed function will call another non-publicly exposed function in an AMD module. Is it better to put the function outside of the return (outsideReturnPrivate) or inside of the return (insideReturnPrivate) and why?

```
// libFile.js
define(function() {
    'use strict';
    var outsideReturnPrivate = function(test) {}; //Is this better?
    return function () {
        var insideReturnPrivate = function(test) {}, //Is this better?
            insideReturnPublic = function(test) {
                // which is better and why?
                // var example = insideReturnPrivate(test);
                // var example = outsideReturnPrivate(test);
                // return example;
            };
        return {
            insideReturnPublic: insideReturnPublic
        };
    }
});
```

```
// consumer
var example = require('libFile.js'),
    test = 'test',
    result = example.insideReturnPublic(test);
```

edit: changed private function to AMD module with non-publicly exposed

edit 2: added more clarity to example

Comment: There is no public/private in JS, there is only "scope". Since plain JS doesn't have `define()`: which framework are you asking about? For JS in general, you define your code in the scope where it gets declared the least number of times (ideally, once) while shielding it from unwanted access. If you use any kind of module (es modules or node/rjs/etc) then typically "at the module level" is perfectly fine.

Comment: Do note that JS does not have private members. This pseudo-private behavior is achieved by scoping and closures. So as long as you can hide your function inside the module's closure and still have access to the variables it needs, it doesn't matter which scope you put it in.

Comment: we use AMD. I've updated the title and question. Is there any practical difference between outsideReturnPrivate and insideReturnPrivate?

Comment: In your given example, there appears to be no purpose for a closure at all. It doesn't appear to accomplish anything significant.

Comment: this was just for the examples sake. In actual code this could be a library module that has publically exposed methods which call non-exposed functions